# Select method missing from intellisense with Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I might be really overlooking something, but when creating a class using the Linq to Entities linq statements, the **Select** method is missing from the intellisense!

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with EntityFrameWork 6.0.2.

I have the following code snippet and the next closest methods in the intellisense is **RemoveRange** and **SingleAsync**. **In between is where I should find the Select**!

I'd like to get a subset of the properties from the Ratings class and not all of them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AjaxCallModel;
using AjaxCallModel.ViewModels;

namespace WcfServiceLibraryAjaxCall
{
    public class AjaxCall : IAjaxCall
    {
        public async Task<List<Rating>> SelectRatingsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using (BillYeagerEntities DbContext = new BillYeagerEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    var ratings = await DbContext.Ratings.ToListAsync();

                    return ratings;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

If I compare it to another project I have, there's not an issue (see the code below).

**Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or missing?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using YeagerTechModel;
using YeagerTechModel.DropDownLists;
using YeagerTechModel.ViewModels;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task<List<ProjectName>> GetProjectNameDropDownListAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            var project = await DbContext.Projects.Select(s =>
                new ProjectName()
                {
                    ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                    Name = s.Name
                }).ToListAsync();

            return project;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: `using System.Linq` is missing.

Comment: @DaveSwersky That's an entirely different problem that just has the same symptoms.  Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy Looks like you're right... hard to believe this question hasn't been asked before...

Comment: @DaveSwersky I'm sure it has.  I've seen some personally.

Comment: MarcinJuraszek, you hit it right on the head. I don't see how I overlooked that. Thanks so much!

Comment: How do I give you credit for the answer? I can't vote for my own post....

Answer (score 8):

Add the namespace System.Linq to your cs file

using System.Linq;

Comment: This is because, `Select()`, `Sum`, `Where` etc all are *extension methods* which are not declared in the collection classes, but in seperate namespace `System.Linq`